# Win32API for window focalization

Tags: winapi

I want to use API functions to set focus on one window under Windows (XP , Vista , 7 (whatever , any version who support .NET 3.0 or later)). So that when you press a key , the OS changes focus to another window.

Thanks

P.S: If you know any class in .NET 2.0 (or later) with which I can develop this solution I'd like you to tell me about it.

Comment: Focalizate...really?  That is...not a word at best.

Comment: I assume it means, "set window focus". I want to know whether the asker wants a Win32 API function or something in the .NET BCL, since the title and question text contradict a little.

Comment: Also, you ask for a Win32 solution, but you then ask for a .NEt solution.  Which is it?

Comment: What's wrong with Focalizate? It's a perfectly cromulent word.

Comment: I wish just to change the focalization

Answer (score 2):

You could p/invoke [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539(VS.85).aspx).  This will bring a window forward and focus on it.

This does require that you have the windows HWND.

As a side note, user's do not appreciate unexpectedly focusing a window; so use with caution.  Additionally, Windows will not necessarily actually bring the window forward; it may instead just "flash" the title bar under some circumstances.

Comment: Yes, flashing the title bar is supposed to be the correct (documented) behavior.

Comment: There are still conditions where the foreground window will change.  They are documented.  Generally, Window's tries to make it hard to abuse focus but its hardly 100% successful in that endeavor.

Comment: Yeah, I know; one of our apps does this and I hate it.